# The numbers from 1 to 20 (do not use arrays)

Tags: javascript

I need to show in **console** the numbers from 1 to 20 without an array..that s what i did:

```
function oneToTwenty() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    print i;
  }
}
console.log(i);
```

what is wrong?

Comment: ``for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) { console.log(i); }``

Answer (score 2):

The `console.log(i);` should be inside the `for` loop:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no such thing  as "print". use console.log instead of print.

You also have an extra closing "}", which doesn't make sense.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: ohh,the extra closing "}" is from the function,this is inside a function

Comment: yes, I figured that, but when posting code you need to be very careful. adding an extra } changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `console.log` inside the loop. Otherwise, you firstly do the looping and then try to log the non-existent `i`.
Also, note that you have to declare `i`, if you have not done it, using `var` or `let`.

```
  for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
```